# wxWidgets and fetch_content in cmake

Tags: cmake, wxwidgets

I want to use fetch_content with wxWidgets. So far I have this and it "works". but Im not sure what I should link in the target_link_libraries.
main.cpp is a hello world example and it doesnt compile because it can't find the #include <wx/wxprec.h>

**Edit1**
I managed to get the cmake script running with adding the libraries manually. Problem remains that it doesnt link on windows so far and only worked on arch linux once.
**Edit2**
This cmake works and builds on windows and linux.

```
    include(FetchContent)
    
    
    if (MSVC)
        add_executable(_TARGET_
            WIN32
            src/main.cpp
        )
    else()
        add_executable(_TARGET_
            src/main.cpp
        )
    endif()
    
    # ------------------ wxWidgets ------------------
    set(wxBUILD_SHARED OFF CACHE BOOL "Build wx libraries as shared libs")
    set(wxBUILD_PRECOMP OFF CACHE BOOL "Use precompiled headers")
    set(wxBUILD_MONOLITHIC OFF CACHE BOOL "Build a single library")
    
    FetchContent_Declare(
        wxWidgets 
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets.git
        GIT_TAG        v3.1.4
        GIT_SHALLOW     TRUE
    )
    
    FetchContent_GetProperties(wxWidgets)
    FetchContent_MakeAvailable(wxWidgets)
    
    target_link_libraries(foo
        wxbase
        wxcore
        wxnet
    )
```

Comment: what are the exact error message(s) you receive? Are you able to compile the `minimal` samle provided with wxWidgets? What OS/compiler you are trying to run it on?

Comment: Are you able to find wx/wx.h or wx/wxprec.h? I am having a compilation problem on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and provide my answer for completeness (even though late), but might be of use for someone googling their way to this question ...

To remove the include error around #include <wx/wxprec.h>, you need to specify also the include directories where these files are located, in my case I have something like:

```cpp
add_executable(foo WIN32 "")
target_include_directories(stlGUI PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_SOURCE_DIR}/include/msvc)
target_include_directories(stlGUI PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

That get's rid of the include error. In your case, it seems that you are compiling wxWidgets as a static library. I found that in order to make these static libraries visible, you should also include the directories for the linker, i.e.

```cpp
target_link_directories(foo PRIVATE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/vc_x64_lib/)
```

If you wanted to compile it as a shared library (or someone else), I have found that the library include path can be incorrectly constructed. CMake needs additional info which is not handled by the FetchContent_MakeAvailable function. I encountered an error message which said something like

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: '../../../lib/vc_x64_lib/mswd/wx/setup.h': No such file or directory.
```

In my case, the setup.h file was actually located in `../../../lib/vc_x64_dll/mswud/wx/setup.h`, i.e. note that it is dll, not lib and mswud, not mswd. The first problem can be addressed by telling wxWidgets that we are using DLLs, not LIBs (even though we configured it to be a shared library, there is probably an option during configuration we could set but that step is abstracted away for us through FetchContent_Declare) ... anyhow, we need to define some preprocessor macros, for the DLL part, we have to include

```cpp
target_compile_definitions(foo PRIVATE WXUSINGDLL=1)
```

Similarily, to get the u in mswud (which stands for unicode support), we need to tell CMake to use unicode with

```cpp
target_compile_definitions(foo PRIVATE _UNICODE=1)
```

That should now compile the libraries. Once you start linking it against your executable as in your example, you may get runtime errors that the libraries are not found. Either copy the libraries which can't be found from the `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/vc_x64_dll` folder into your folder holding the executable (typically `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Debug/`, i.e. have your *.dll files side by side with your *.exe files or specify the environmental variable PATH (windows) or LD_LIBRARY_PATH (UNIX) to point to your folder holding the libraries. You can do that in CMake as well

```cpp
# set RPATH to find dynamic libraries at runtime (windows only)
if (WIN32)
  set(ENV{PATH} "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/vc_x64_dll;$ENV{PATH}")
endif()
```

Hope this will be of use, there seems to be very little documentation for this issue and it took me way too many hours to fix this. The above is not perfect (and only really tested for windows though I expect the approach to work on UNIX as well with modifications to the variable names) but hopefully a starting point for others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The below cmake script will work on both windows and Linux. I have tested it using clang,msvc compilers in windows 11 and with gcc in ubuntu 22.04

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project(PRACTICE LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(wxWidgets_USE_STATIC 1)
set(wxBUILD_SHARED OFF)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
   wxWidgets
   GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets.git
   GIT_TAG v3.2.1
)
FetchContent_GetProperties(wxwidgets)
if(NOT wxwidgets_POPULATED)
   FetchContent_Populate(wxwidgets)
   add_subdirectory(${wxwidgets_SOURCE_DIR} ${wxwidgets_BUILD_DIR})
endif()

set(SRCS src/frame.cpp src/main.cpp)
add_executable(main WIN32 ${SRCS})

target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE wx::base wx::core)
```